# Remove key property from JSON object using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

My initial object:

```
var data=[  
 {  
  "parent":104,
  "child":130,
  "grandChild":755,
  "greatGrandChild":576
 },
 {  
  "parent":106
 },
 {  
  "parent":109
 }
]
```

The code to generate the object

```
var nodes=[], levels = ["parent","child","grandChild","greatGrandChild"];
 data.forEach(function(d){
var depthCursor=nodes;
levels.forEach(function( property, depth ){
    var index;
    if(depthCursor!==undefined){
    depthCursor.forEach(function(child,i){
        if ( d[property] == child.text ) index = i;
    });
    if ( isNaN(index) ) {
        depthCursor.push({ text : d[property], nodes : []});
        index = depthCursor.length - 1;
    }
    depthCursor = depthCursor[index].nodes;
    if(d.greatGrandChild!=="" && d.greatGrandChild !==undefined && d.greatGrandChild!==null){
        if ( depth === levels.length - 1 ) {
            depthCursor.push({ name : d.greatGrandChild });
        }
    }else if(d.grandChild!=="" && d.grandChild !==undefined && d.grandChild!==null){
        if ( depth === levels.length - 2 ) {
            depthCursor.push({ name : d.grandChild });
        }
    }else if(d.child!=="" && d.child !==undefined && d.child!==null){
        if ( depth === levels.length - 3 ) {

            depthCursor.push({ name : d.child });
        }
    }else if(d.parent!=="" && d.parent !==undefined && d.parent!==null){
         if (depth === levels.length - 4 ) {
             depthCursor.push({ name : d.parent});
         }
    }
    }
});
});
```

I have an array of objects. The last node is created with the value of parent text which is incorrect

```
 [  
  {"text":104,
   "nodes":[  
             {"text":130,
              "nodes":[  
                        {"text":755,
                         "nodes":[  
                                   {"text":576,
                                    "nodes":[
                                             {"name":576}
                                           ]
                                    }
                                 ]
                         }
                      ]
              }
            ]
   },
   {"text":106,
    "nodes":[  
              {"name":106}
            ]
   },
   {"text":109,
    "nodes":[  
             {"name":109}
           ]
   }
]
```

**The desired output**

```
[
  {"text": 104,
   "nodes": [
              {"text": 130,
               "nodes": [
                          {"text": 755,
                           "nodes": [
                                      {"text": 576}
                                    ]
                          }
                        ]
             }
           ]
 },
 {"text": 106},
 {"text": 109}
]
```

I want to remove the last node appended. I have tried lot of ways to remove it but nothing worked. Kindly help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you getting the first object ?

Answer (score 0):

you can make a function deletes the object with no node key and call this function recursively.

```js
var arr =  [  
  {"text":104,
   "nodes":[  
         {"text":130,
          "nodes":[  
                    {"text":755,
                     "nodes":[  
                               {"text":576,
                                "nodes":[
                                         {"name":576}
                                       ]
                                }
                             ]
                     }
                  ]
          }
        ]
   },
   {"text":106,
"nodes":[  
          {"name":106}
        ]
   },
   {"text":109,
"nodes":[  
         {"name":109}
       ]
   }
];
function removeNode(obj){
    if(obj.nodes[0].hasOwnProperty('nodes'))
       removeNode(obj.nodes[0]);
    else
       delete obj.nodes;
}

arr.forEach(function(v){
removeNode(v);
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner way to generate the object in the first place would be to use the recursion.
Look at the below snippet:

```js
var data=[  
 {  
  "parent":104,
  "child":130,
  "grandChild":755,
  "greatGrandChild":576
 },
 {  
  "parent":106
 },
 {  
  "parent":109
 }
];

var levels = ["parent","child","grandChild","greatGrandChild"];
var nodes = data.map(function(obj) {
  return generate(obj, levels);
});

function generate(obj, levels) {
  var r = {};
  if(obj[levels[0]]) {
    r.text = obj[levels[0]];
    if(obj[levels[1]]) {
      r.nodes = [generate(obj, levels.slice(1))];
    }
  }
  return r;
}


console.log(nodes);
```